# Hover multiple element Not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to hover multiple input elements, they will toggle a class on the corresponding element.

The problem I have with my code is that sometime an element got stuck and I need to move the mouse out from the input element in order to toggle the class.

Why is it doing this? Is there a easy and clean way to do this?

**//UPDATE**

On chrome works fine.. safari is the problem.

```js
// address
var addressInput = $('.menu__item input[name="dashAddress"]');
addressInput.hover(function() {
  $('.dottedElement').removeClass('dottedElement');
  $('.myAddress').addClass('dottedElement');
  $('.card-img-div-flip').toggleClass("card-img-div-flip-Active");
});
addressInput.keyup(function() {
  var stt = $(this).val();
  $(".myAddress").text(stt);
});

// phone
var phoneInput = $('.menu__item input[name="dashPhone"]');
phoneInput.hover(function() {
  $('.dottedElement').removeClass('dottedElement');
  $('.myPhone').toggleClass('dottedElement');
});
phoneInput.keyup(function() {
  var stt = $(this).val();
  $(".myPhone").text(stt);
});

// phone
var webInput = $('.menu__item input[name="dashWeb"]');
webInput.hover(function() {
  $('.dottedElement').removeClass('dottedElement');
  $('.myWeb').toggleClass('dottedElement');
});
webInput.keyup(function() {
  var stt = $(this).val();
  $(".myWeb").text(stt);
});

// phone
var catInput = $('.menu__item input[name="dashCat"]');
catInput.hover(function() {
  $('.dottedElement').removeClass('dottedElement');
  $('.myCat').toggleClass('dottedElement');
});
catInput.keyup(function() {
  var stt = $(this).val();
  $(".myCat").text(stt);
});
```

```css
.dottedElement {
    background: yellow;
    border: 1px dotted red;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
<li class="menu__item">
  <input class="menu_input" type="text" name="dashAddress" placeholder="Business Address" />
</li>
<li class="menu__item">
  <input class="menu_input" type="text" name="dashPhone" placeholder="Business Phone" />
</li>
<li class="menu__item">
  <input class="menu_input" type="text" name="dashWeb" placeholder="Business Web" />
</li>
<li class="menu__item">
  <input class="menu_input" type="text" name="dashCat" placeholder="Business Cat" />
</li>
</div>

<div>
</BR></BR>
<a class="myAddress" href="" target="_blank"><span>ADDRESS</span></a>
</BR></BR>
<a class="myPhone" href="" target="_blank"><span>Phone</span></a>
</BR></BR>
<a class="myWeb" href="" target="_blank"><span>Web</span></a>
</BR></BR>
<a class="myCat" href="" target="_blank"><span>Category</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: `$().hover` has two parameters. the first one is fired when you hover the element, the second one is fired when you leave the element. You could add the class using the first function and remove inside the second function.

Comment: The HTML is invalid. `li` MUST be children of a `ul`...

Comment: Check [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/njnedyus/1/) using `.hover`

Comment: Thanks Daniel.. +1 for the short code.. However, still having issue hovering

Comment: Like this?: http://jsfiddle.net/6fyeS/53/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("li").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass('hover);
  }, 
  function () {
   $(this).removeClass("hover");
```

}
);

should work work for you...

Comment: Not work as suppose to.. It will highlight the li itself. Need to highlight other elements . This is your try: http://jsfiddle.net/6fyeS/51/

Answer (score 0):

If you slightly change the structure of your HTML (remove the div around the li's), you can do it with pure CSS:

```
.menu__item:nth-of-type(1):hover ~ div a.myAddress{
  background:yellow;
}
.menu__item:nth-of-type(2):hover ~ div a.myPhone{
  background:yellow;
}
.menu__item:nth-of-type(3):hover ~ div a.myWeb{
  background:yellow;
}
.menu__item:nth-of-type(4):hover ~ div a.myCat{
  background:yellow;
}
```

Your HTML would have to look like this:

```
<li class="menu__item">
      <input class="menu_input" type="text" name="dashAddress" placeholder="Business Address" />
</li>
<li class="menu__item">
      <input class="menu_input" type="text" name="dashPhone" placeholder="Business Phone" />
</li>
<li class="menu__item">
      <input class="menu_input" type="text" name="dashWeb" placeholder="Business Web" />
</li>
<li class="menu__item">
      <input class="menu_input" type="text" name="dashCat" placeholder="Business Cat" />
</li>

<div>
    <br><a class="myAddress" href="" target="_blank"><span>ADDRESS</span></a><br>
    <a class="myPhone" href="" target="_blank"><span>Phone</span></a><br>
    <a class="myWeb" href="" target="_blank"><span>Web</span></a><br>
    <a class="myCat" href="" target="_blank"><span>Category</span></a>
</div>
```

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6hrbdv2j/).

Comment: Thank you.. I have thought about css... Unfortunately I cannot change my html structure